# Pasting tabs from Excel into bash

Tags: excel, bash, tabs, paste, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to paste several columns from excel with tab delimitations into a bash text editor (nano), but the tabs are not being written. I'm using the windows 10 Linux subsystem (no problem from my mac). Any idea how to get bash to recognise tabs?

Many thanks.

Comment: Sample input and output maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured this out! Under bash properties and edit options, just need to unclick filter clipboard contents on paste! Simple, if you know it!!